# Flex-Disable data grid row when checkbox is not selected

Tags: apache-flex, checkbox

I am writing flex code

1. first column has checkboxes
2. When checkbox is slected then only particular row in datadrid should be enabled, i.e. all other columns I need to enable for particular row

As I am using itemrenderer in each datagridcolumn I can not access its id's outside.

How can I disable or enable rows based on checkbox change?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a row could have different meanings. But if your intention is to disallow the user from being able to edit the row, even when the editable property of the datagrid is set to true, you could use the `event:ListEvent` and its property`event.preventDefault()` to achieve this.

On the click of the check-box column, call a function and store the rowIndex through the `ListEvent` into a global variable `checkedIndex`. Call the function below on the itemClick property of the datagrid.

```
public function disableEditing(event:ListEvent):void
{   
    if(event.columnIndex == 0)
        //call a function & assign the value into global var checkedIndex
    else
    {
        var currentIndex: Number = event.rowIndex;
        if (currentIndex != checkedIndex)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

More info on ListEvent [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ListEvent.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
I tried using preventDefault, it disables columns but I am not able to enable it back.

To be specific with my requirement I have 3 columns,
First contains checkbox and other two contains text boxes,all of these are inside separate itemrenderers of datagrid columns

If checkbox is checked subsequent textboxes in particular row should be editable
and when checkbox is unchecked textboxes should not be editable

Comment: Could you share your code, so that we can see how you are achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

From inside of itemrenderer, you can access the record data by using `data.fieldname`.
So if you want to change dynamically based on other columns, it doesn't need to [access id of component which is inside itemrender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36530672/access-id-of-component-which-is-inside-itemrender-in-parent-application).
Just bind the data.

```
<mx:TextInput enabled="{data.isChecked}"/>  <!-- For Flex3 -->
<s:TextInput enabled="{data.isChecked}"/>   <!-- For Flex4 -->
```

Working Example: http://wonderfl.net/c/6MS0

Comment: This solution looks awesome,But when I call refresh it also applies default sorter which I have implemented for checkbox column,and selected row moves to top of the table causing super dynamic sorting which I dont want.I just need data to be sorted by default when page is loaded.That is why I wanted to know if we can have some other option than refresh